# Automatically add attachments to an email sent with email quick action?

Tags: trigger, email

Depending on some factors I need to add attachments to an email that is send out using the standard email quick action.

I would like to avoid writing a new component and then send the email itself from code, if at all possible. Triggers on EmailMessage apparently are not the solution, as the message is stored after being sent.

Is there anything that fires before an email is actually sent so that I can intercept and manipulate the message & add attachments?

Or if I have to create my own component, is there any good starting point for an email component as close to the email quick action as possible?